# Last digit of 2^n

Tags: c#

Last digit of 2^n without calculate the number.
n=(0,1000000) or bigger.

Comment: You can't know the answer without performing the calculation.  And if you've performed the calculation then you've already stored the result some where.

Comment: in binary its always 0 - and we are talking about computers here so that probably what you want

Comment: @Marius98 You should check out my answer.

Comment: "or bigger" is vague. `Int32` can go up to two _billion_.

Comment: @LordWilmore that's not always true: you sometimes *can* calculate partial results; but this is a math question, more than a programming question. Marius, I recommend asking yourself the question without thinking of programming it. Instead "How would I do it on paper?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the sequence of powers of two, you will se a pattern:

1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048

its always 2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 6

You can use this, to calculate the last digit

```
int GetLastDigit(int power)
{
    if (power == 0) return 1;
    switch ((power - 1) % 4)
    {
        case 0: return 2;
        case 1: return 4; 
        case 2: return 8; 
        case 3: return 6;
        default: return -1; //negative power.
    } 
}
```

BigInteger version:

```
static int GetLastDigit(BigInteger power)
{
    if (power == 0) return 1;
    switch ((int)((power - 1) % 4)) //you can cast it, because it will always be less than 4
    {
        case 0: return 2;
        case 1: return 4;
        case 2: return 8;
        case 3: return 6;
        default: return -1; //negative power. 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is right but is not what i am searching.

Comment: You wanted the last digit of the number.

Comment: If i have a number that can't be store in a int or a long what i can do?

Comment: You can replace int power with BigInteger power

Comment: `power == 0 ? 1 : (new[] { 2,4,8,6 })[(power-1) % 4]` :)

Comment: @Marius98 Your question specifically says that `n` is in the range of (0, 1000000).  One million fits in an `int`.

Comment: if i would store it in an array?

Comment: @Marius98 NetMage just made my code a one-liner; it's in no way any faster.

Comment: hmm i will use BigInteger, thanks for your time

Comment: I think marius thinks you are calculating 2^n, not really reading your answer

Comment: @pm100 yeah, it is not that complicated tho .. :/

Comment: however - do we have actual proof of this, I mean math is full of empirical results that turn out to be false. maybe math.stackexchange would know better

Comment: @pm100 Any such cycle would be a result of the way our base-10 digit system interacts with powers of two. It should not be difficult to prove.

Comment: @pm100 Proof: https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-the-last-digit-of-a-power/

Comment: @pm100 It's 10th grade maths

Comment: that link doesnt prove it - it just says that it cycles

Comment: @ rokkerboci i will accept your answer, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Simplest approach would be this:

```
public static int LastDigit(int n)
{
    var last = n %4;
    return (int)Math.Pow(2, last) + (last == 0 && n != 0 ? 5 : 0);
}
```

So, basically, you just take last byte (last 2 bits) of your power and checking whether entire number is zero. The answer can be encoded in total of 3 bits.

More general approach for large numbers (represented in BigEndian):

```
public static int LastDigit(byte[] n)
{
    var last = n[n.Length - 1] %4;
    return (int)Math.Pow(2, last) + ((last == 0 && !(n.Length == 1 && n[0] == 0)) ? 5 : 0);
}
```

So, for BigInteger:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pow = new BigInteger(12);
        var value = Math.Pow(2, (int)pow);
        var lastDigit = LastDigit(pow.ToByteArray());
    }

    public static int LastDigit(byte[] n)
    {
        var last = n[n.Length - 1] %4;
        return (int)Math.Pow(2, last) + ((last == 0 && !(n.Length == 1 && n[0] == 0)) ? 5 : 0);
    }
}
```

Doesn't really matter how big it is actually. All you need is just to know whether or not it is zero, and 2 last bits.

Comment: this is basically a more complicated version of @rokkerboci answer

Comment: Nope, this is version that actually accepts BigInteger. Though, the more I think the more Im confident that he given a string instead of BigInteger. So, he basically needs 2 last character. I can write extension, but it will look ugly. Just like any boolean/discrete math out there. It is already ugly, though.